# Classes and vectors

Tags: c++

I have this classes below and I want to save a HomePC to a vector, what's the method that I can do that, and how can I print the first or the second element from the vector.

```
class PC
{
public:
    PC(string in_operatingSystem,int in_ramSlots,int in_pcieSlots,int in_totalRamSlots, int in_gbPerRam, int in_cpu, int in_ssd, int in_cost);

    virtual void Print() = 0;
    virtual void Upgrade() = 0;
protected:
    string operatingSystem;
    int ramSlots,pcieSlots,totalRamSlots,gbPerRam;
    int cpu,ssd;
    int cost;
};

class HomePC: public PC
{
public:
    HomePC(string in_operatingSystem,int in_ramSlots,int in_pcieSlots,int in_totalRamSlots, int in_gbPerRam, int in_cpu, int in_ssd, int in_cost, string in_model);

    void Print();
    void Upgrade();
private:
    string model;
};
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt to add an instance to a vector?

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
// create
std::vector<HomePC> homePcs;

// insert
homePcs.push_back(HomePC{...});
// or
homePcs.emplace_back(...);

// get and print
std::cout << homePcs[0] << " " << homePcs[1] << '\n';
```

I highly recommend learning how to use [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), as this site could have easily answered your question.

Comment: What's the format of the vector after that? for example if I push_back ("MacOS",2,3,4,...) what's the first element of the vector?

Comment: The first element of the vector is the first element which you inserted, then comes the second one which you inserted etc. Note that your syntax for `push_back` is false. You can use `emplace_back` to directly forward the arguments like in your example or you can use `push_back({"MacOs", 2, 3, 4, ...})` to keep it simple.

Comment: Undefined symbol: vtable for HomePC, got this, any idea?

Comment: Did you define, not just declare `HomePC::Print()` and `HomePC::Upgrade()` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:
`vector<PC*> myPCs;` 
`myPCs.push_pack(new HomePC(...));` to create your vector and add HomePC object in this vector. 
Also you need to include library for using vector: `#include <vector>` and write `using namespace std;` below including line.

Comment: You would need a `vector<PC*>`, not `vector<PC>` for that. Also using a `vector<unique_ptr<PC>>` and inserting `make_unique<HomePC>` would be much safer.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutly correct, thanks. I've edited my answer

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5910058)

Answer (score 0):

```
//First create the vector which will store the objects
std::vector<HomePC> homePcs;


// Create the object to push into the vector
HomePC temp;  //i named it temp as it will be used only to pass the object

//After inputing data in temp with accessors/mutators , just store it in the vector created

homePcs.push_back(temp);
```

You can print easily by using a for loop and the **.size()** methods in vector , to know how many times the loop should iterate.

```
for(int i=0;i<homePcs.size();i++)
{
    std::cout<<homePcs[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You can loop through a vector in a much prettier way by using a range-based for: `for (const auto &pc : homePcs) {std::cout << pc << '\n';}` Also the use of `std::endl`is excessive here, see [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).